# Aerowindow like windows7 using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to generate Boxes in the Aero Style in Window7 style using jquery.The popup window should offer the usual options and full functionality similar to Windows windows.How is it possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this plugin

i use it its very nice

http://www.soyos.net/aerowindow-jquery.html

Comment: i am trying to find some help with this jquery template (windows 7 dekstop) but i think the company has closed.. I am trying to reach the support or the forum (http://www.soyos.net/community/) but it gives errros..
I have very big issue.. when i am uploading the aero window 7 to a server online, everything works except the task bar hidden .. but it works.. I have upload the project here (http://markoskarpodinis.epizy.com/test/)

All the images etc.. are uploaded correct